# Hibernate and Thymeleaf infinite recursion

Tags: java, javascript, hibernate, thymeleaf

I have 2 classes with one atribute mapped with OneToMany/ManyToOne relation. The problem is that when i do the select and pass to te view, i want to parse the object to javascript with Thymeleaf, but it loop infinite cause of the relation.
My to classes:
Class Player:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name = "level")
private int level;

@Column(name = "experience")
private int experience;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="player", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<InventoryItem> inventory;

// Constructor
public Player() {
}

// Getters & Setters...
}
```

Class InventoryItem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory_item")
public class InventoryItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_player")
    private Player player;


    public InventoryItem() {
    }

    //Getters and Setters...
}
```

Then i pass the Player object to the view and console.log it with javascript:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    console.log([[${player}]]);
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

And this is the error:
[image]

How can i prevent the bi-directional relation when parsing to javascript, something like ignore the `Player` atrubute from all the `InventoryItems`?

Answer (score 5):

I faced this problem today and I guess Thymeleaf does not offer an easy solution for that. You can always set the references to the parent to `null` before passing it to Thymeleaf, but that seems kind of ugly.

Investigating Thymeleaf's source code, I noticed that it uses [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) to get information about the properties, so we can hide some properties by implementing a `BeanInfo`. The easiest way to do that is to create a class on the same package of your bean, with `BeanInfo` appended to the name. You can extend `SimpleBeanInfo` and implement only the methods that interest you (in this case `getPropertyDescriptors`).

In your example, you could do:

```
public class InventoryItemBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {
    @Override
    public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
        try {  
            PropertyDescriptor id = new PropertyDescriptor("id", InventoryItem.class);         
            PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = {id};
            return descriptors;
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            throw new Error(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This way, Thymeleaf wouldn't see your `Player` property and you wouldn't have the infinite recursion anymore.

The downside of this solution is that you have to remember that everytime you change the attributes of your `InventoryItem` bean you have to go to your `BeanInfo` and add the new attribute to it.

So I came up with another solution. It's a little bit more complicated, but once it's set up it's easier to maintain.

We start by creating an annotation to indicate that the property should be hidden. Let's call it `HiddenProperty`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface HiddenProperty {}
```

Now we implement a generic `BeanInfo` class that will inspect a bean using reflection and find the properties. We will also check for the existence of our annotation and when it's present we ignore the method:

```
public class HiddenPropertyAwareBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {
    private Class<?> beanClass;
    private PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors;

    public HiddenPropertyAwareBeanInfo(Class<?> beanClass) {
        this.beanClass = beanClass;
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
        if(descriptors != null) {
            return descriptors;
        }

        Method[] methodList = beanClass.getMethods();
        List<PropertyDescriptor> propDescriptors = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Method m : methodList) {
            if(Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers())) {
                continue;
            }

            try {
                if(m.getParameterCount() == 0 && !m.isAnnotationPresent(HiddenProperty.class)) {
                    if(m.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                        propDescriptors.add(new PropertyDescriptor(m.getName().substring(3), beanClass));
                    } else if(m.getName().startsWith("is")) {
                        propDescriptors.add(new PropertyDescriptor(m.getName().substring(2), beanClass));
                    }
                }
            } catch(IntrospectionException ex) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        descriptors = new PropertyDescriptor[propDescriptors.size()];
        return propDescriptors.toArray(descriptors);
    }
}
```

Now, create your `BeanInfo` that extends this class:

```
public class InventoryItemBeanInfo extends HiddenPropertyAwareBeanInfo {
    public InventoryItemBeanInfo() {
        super(InventoryItem.class);
    }
}
```

Finally, annotate the getters of the properties you want to hide:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory_item")
public class InventoryItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_player")
    private Player player;


    public InventoryItem() {
    }

    @HiddenProperty
    public Player getPlayer() {
        return this.player;
    }
    //Other getters and setters...
}
```

And there you have it. Now you can change your properties as much as you want and your `Player` property will not be seen by Thymeleaf.

One important thing to say about this solution is that it is not 100% compliant with the Java Beans spec, it doesn't consider the existence of indexed properties and some other details. You can take a look at the `Introspector`'s [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/beans/Introspector.java#494) to see how they extract this information and improve this solution.

But, personally, I think this should be fixed inside Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf is an incredibly elegant tool and having to resort to that kind of workaround makes me kind of sad.

Comment: I used your first suggestion and set the reference to the parent to null and that worked